# What's the C# pattern to perform an action on a series of values?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(Key.Orange) == KeyState.Lock)
    PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(Function.Orange, 0, 0);

if (PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(Key.Blue) == KeyState.Lock)
    PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(Function.Blue, 0, 0);

if (PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(Key.Shift) == KeyState.Lock)
    PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(Function.Shift, 0, 0);

if (PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(Key.Control) == KeyState.Lock)
    PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(Function.Control, 0, 0);

...
```

and I want to refactor the code separating the key / function definition from the
actions. Key.xxx and Function.xxx aren't from the same type.

eg: in Python, I could simply do something like:

```
keys = (
    ( Key.Orange, Function.Orange ),
    ( Key.Blue  , Function.Blue ),
    ( Key.Shift , Function.Shift ),
    ...
    )

psi_key = PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard

for key, func in keys:
    if psi_key.GetModifierKeyState(key) == KeyState.Lock):
        psi_key.InjectKeyboardCommand(func, 0, 0)
```

What's "the right way" to do in C#?

Comment: @Jimmy: I like how you assume he's assuming. Perhaps he's new? In any case, `for` in C# won't do what he's asking. He needs to use `foreach`.

Comment: I wish we could downvote comments because @Jimmy Hoffa that isn't needed around here.

Comment: @Jimmy: I'm aware of foreach, but I was looking for a non-verbose way to build the initial array.
And yes, I'm a C# newbie (sorry about that)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something very similar:

```
Dictionary<Key, Function> keys = new Dictionary<Key, Function>
{
    { Key.Orange, Function.Orange },
    { Key.Blue, Function.Blue }
    ...
};

foreach (var pair in keys)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(pair.Key) == KeyState.Locked)
    {
        Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(pair.Value, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

You could even use LINQ if you wanted to:

```
foreach (var pair in keys.Where(pair => 
                 Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(pair.Key) == KeyState.Locked)
{
    Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(pair.Value, 0, 0);
}
```

Now using a `Dictionary` is somewhat odd here given that we're not looking anything up. If you're using .NET 4 you could use a list of tuples instead:

```
var keys = new List<Tuple<Key, Function>>()
{
    Tuple.Of(Key.Orange, Function.Orange),
    Tuple.Of(Key.Blue, Function.Blue),
    ...
};
```

and adjust the loop accordingly. You could use an anonymous type, too:

```
var keys = new[]
{
    new { Key = Key.Orange, Function = Function.Orange },
    new { Key = Key.Blue, Function = Function.Blue },
    ...
};
```

They're all basically acting as ways of representing key/function pairs :)

Comment: Note a potential problem with the `Dictionary` implementation:  The order of pairs **out** is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of pairs **in**.  If this order matters, then this may be a problem.  However, given the current implementation (in .NET, not sure about Mono), I believe it *will* return the pairs in the same order they were added, since none is ever removed.

Comment: thanks, the anonymous type works fine! The other alternatives aren't available: I'm using .NET CF 2, sorry I didn't mention it before.

Comment: @P Daddy: I think you're right on all counts - and it definitely shouldn't be depended on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Key and Function are enumerations, you could also try:

```
foreach (Key key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key))) 
{
    if (PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(key) == KeyState.Lock)
    {
        PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand((Function)Enum.Parse(typeof(Function), key.ToString()), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using PsionTeklogix.Keyboard; /* assuming that's a namespace, */
                              /* otherwise, you can optionally do: */
/* using Keyboard = PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard; */

class Foo{
    static readonly Key[] keys = {Key.Orange, Key.Blue, Key.Shift, ...};
    static readonly Function[] functions = {Function.Orange, Function.Blue, Function.Shift, ...};

    static void Main(){
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            if(Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(keys[i]) == KeyState.Lock)
                Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(func, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since it looks like both `Key` and `Function` are enums, **and** you use the same `Function` enum value name for each `Key` enum value, you can do something like this, which is slightly prettier, if a slight bit slower:

```
static readonly string[] values = {"Orange", "Blue", "Shift", ...};

static void Main(){
    foreach(string value in values)
        if(Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState((Key)Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), value)) == KeyState.Lock);
            Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand((Function)Enum.Parse(typeof(Function), value), 0, 0);
}
```

Okay, maybe it's not prettier.  Meh.

But, if the *values* of `Key` are also the same as the values of `Function` (that is, if `(int)Key.Orange == (int)Function.Orange`, etc.), then you can do something like:

```
static readonly Key[] keys = {Key.Orange, Key.Blue, Key.Shift, ...};

static void Main(){
    foreach(Key key in keys)
        if(Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(key) == KeyState.Lock);
            Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand((Function)key, 0, 0);
}
```

None of these is a *direct* equivalent of the Python code, which would be more like this:

```
class KeyFunction{
    readonly Key      key;
    readonly Function function;

    public Key      Key     {get{return key;}}
    public Function Function{get{return function;}}

    public KeyFunction(Key key, Function function){
        this.key      = key;
        this.function = function;
    }
}

static readonly KeyFunction[] keyFunctions = {
    new KeyFunction(Key.Orange, Function.Orange),
    new KeyFunction(Key.Blue,   Key.Blue),
    new KeyFunction(Key.Shift,  Key.Shift),
    ...
};

static void Main(){
    foreach(KeyFunction kf in keyFunctions)
        if(Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(kf.Key) == KeyState.Lock)
            Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(kf.Function, 0, 0);
}
```

That's the most verbose solution of all, but it's the most flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary` for this.

```
Dictionary<Key, Function> map = new Dictionary<Key, Function>();

map.Add(Key.Orange, Function.Orange);
map.Add(Key.Blue, Function.Blue);
map.Add(Key.Shift, Function.Shift);
map.Add(Key.Control, Function.Control);

foreach(var pair in map)
{
    if (PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.GetModifierKeyState(map.Key) == KeyState.Lock)
    {
        PsionTeklogix.Keyboard.Keyboard.InjectKeyboardCommand(map.Value, 0, 0);
    }
}
```